# Accordion dropdown filtering through ion search bar

Tags: ionic-framework

Hi I just created the ionic accordion dropdowns by following a tutorial blog link which used widgets for creating an accordion dropdowns, Below is the link of that blog.

http://masteringionic.com/blog/2019-01-27-creating-a-simple-accordion-widget-in-ionic-4/

updated: here is the my project demo link https://stackblitz.com/github/dSaif/search-accordion
Everything is working perfect, but i want to add Ion-searchbar at the top of the accordions sothat the dropdowns gets filter by inputing text.

please assist me how can i do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to create a variable in your homepage to store your filtered results. Then you need to have a filter function that will take the input from the search bar and filter your master list. Keep in mind you should not set the new variable to the master list, this could cause issues due to object referencing.

So you should have something like

in your html

```
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Search a name." [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (ionChange)="filterList()"></ion-searchbar>
```

In your ts file

```
searchValue: string = '';
filteredList: Array<{ name: string, description: string, image: string }> = this.technologies;

// function called in the html whenever you change the ion searchbar value
private filterList(){
  //Make a variable so as to avoid any flashing on the screen if you set it to an empty array
  const localFilteredList = []
  this.technologies.forEach(currentItem => {
      //here goes your search criteria, in the if statement
      if(currentItem.name && currentItem.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
          localFilteredList.push(currentItem);
      }
  });
  //finally set the global filter list to your newly filtered list
  this.filteredList  = localFilteredList;
}
```

You also need to make sure to reference the filterList variable instead of the current one you are referencing.

Comment: hi @ Andres, thank you for your answer, but it's not working. showing  errors as  masterlist,search value doenst exist. Iam newbie to ionic and angualar. please help me on this.

Comment: masterlist would have to be changed to the name of the variable you have. If you are following the link it would be technologies. I have made some edits to the code to try and clarify, you also need to declare the searchValue variable

Comment: hi @ Andres, I had created this project in github, here is the stackblitz demo link "https://stackblitz.com/github/dSaif/search-accordion"  please check and help me where iam going wrong for the search box filter functionality. thank you

Comment: Made some minor tweaks but was able to get it to work in the link you sent. Please follow what is said in the answer, edited the answer to reflect those tweaks. in the app-accordion don't forget to replace let technology of technologies to let technology of filteredList